# Is the Superman/Aliens crossover canon to Post-Crisis DC comics continuity?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, alien-franchise, dark-horse-comics

In 1995, DC Comics collaborated with Dark Horse Comics to produce the first, three-part *[Superman/Aliens](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman/Aliens_Vol_1)* crossover, scripted and penciled by long-time *Superman* comics writer, Dan Jurgens.

[image: Comic cover of Superman/Aliens]

Are the events of this story actually canon to the [Post-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Post-Crisis) DC comics that were being published at the time though, or was it something more akin to a *[What If...?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_If_(comics))* or *[Elseworlds](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Elseworlds)* tale...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Apparently, this story *is* canon...

... to the Post-Crisis DC comics continuity, as Superman referenced the events of the crossover in *[Superman Vol 2 #119](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_119)*. As with the crossover, this issue was scripted by Dan Jurgens.

[image]